# How to plot a boxplot with correctly spaced continuous x-axis values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot a boxplot where my x-axis is a continuous time-scale which is growing degree days i.e. 0 to 2500. I would like to get a boxplot with x-axis values correctly spaced on a continuous time-scale rather than a discrete one. Normally if it were a regular time/date, I could have used a 'scale_x_date' with ggplot2 in R. However, since the numbers are outside date/time scale I am not sure how can we correctly space the x-axis values. Here is the dummy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
#get data    
df <- data.frame(y=abs(rnorm(8)),
             x=as.factor(rep(c(0,100,200,500),times=2))) 
ggplot(aes(y=y,x=x), data=df) + 
       geom_boxplot()
```

This gives me the plot

[image]

where my x-axis is not spaced based on its numeric values. Instead, I would like to get a boxplot where the spacing between 200 to 500 should be three times more than 100-200. My actual data has x-axis values ranging 0-2500 growing days. I am looking for ggplot2 specific solution preferably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(y=abs(rnorm(8)),
                 x=rep(c(0,100,200,500),times=2)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=x)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

This solution relies on two changes. First, to plot boxes positioned on a continuous x axis, we need to provide numeric rather than factor x values. However, this does not work by itself, because without x values being grouped by factor levels, ggplot no longer knows how to group the data into different boxes. So, we also need to provide an additional grouping variable.

Comment: This works great. On a side note, my actual data has a longer timescale (0 to 2500), which on the full plot stretches the axis to an extent that it makes the boxplots almost look like thin lines. I have tried scaling my axis to '100 units by dividing `x` by 100. But it merges the closer points on x-axis into one point. Do you have any suggestion to remedy this issue?

Comment: you can use the `width=` argument to geom_boxplot.  Set the width in x units

Comment: I think it might be worth to point out that the important step here was to change the x variable in the sample data from categorical to continuous .

Comment: @Tjebotj - thanks,  i added that info to the answer. Also that it requires an additional step beyond that.

Comment: Sorry to re-open an old chain. I am trying to achieve a similar result to this question. I tried using `width=` argument. However this still results in some boxplots being wider than others that are closer together. Do you know how to force the width of the boxplots to stay consistent across the plot? Thanks

Comment: @QPaps  In theory the width argument should be consistent.  I suggest you start a new question on this, including the code and data required to demonstrate your problem reproducibly.  Then we'll be able to identify what's going on more effectively.

Comment: Hi @dww - I have started a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275627/ggplot2-boxplot-width-setting-changes-x-axis). I realised the problem is that it is actually changing the x-axis. If you could take a look it would be greatly appreciated