# Ggplot2 Boxplot width setting changes x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis, boxplot

I have produced a boxplot with a continuous x-axis unsing `geom_boxplot()` in `ggplot2`. However, as there are many boxes they appear as skinny lines. Another stackoverflow chain ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245233/how-to-plot-a-boxplot-with-correctly-spaced-continuous-x-axis-values-in-ggplot2)) suggested using the `width=` argument to make all the boxes the same width. However, when I use this argument it changes the x-axis and some of the boxes just disappear!

For example, take this example dataframe. I apologise for the number of observations this has but I think the quantity has to do with the problem as I couldn't reproduce it with a more simple boxplot:

```
Lat<- c(50.70228,50.70228,50.70228,51.82067,51.82067,51.82067,52.45893,52.45893,52.45893,52.76478,52.76478,52.76478,52.78354,52.78354,52.78354,53.56102,53.56102,53.56102,53.65364,53.65364,53.65364,53.63130,53.63130,53.63130,54.19035,54.19035,54.19035,54.25751,54.25751,54.25751,54.23526,54.23526,54.23526,54.62469,54.62469,54.62469,54.67831,54.67831,54.67831,54.67900,54.67900,54.67900,54.94908,54.94908,54.94908,55.19456,55.19456,55.19456,54.79198,54.79198,54.79198,55.34981,55.34981,55.34981,55.85655,55.85655,55.85655,56.06078,56.06078,56.06078,55.84553,55.84553,55.84553,56.00197,56.00197,56.00197,56.71842,56.71842,56.71842,57.00116,57.00116,57.00116,57.06942,57.06942,57.06942,57.26815,57.26815,57.26815,57.45532,57.45532,57.45532,57.88596,57.88596,57.88596,51.07711,51.07711,51.07711,51.07801,51.07621,51.11159,51.11159,51.11159,52.02484,52.02484,52.02484,52.02581,52.02581,52.02581,52.02685,52.02685,52.02685,52.05353,52.05353,52.05626,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.78968,52.78778,52.78968,52.78968,52.78881,52.78883,52.78883,52.78883,52.78970,52.78970,52.79506,52.79506,52.79506,53.77270,53.77276,53.77109,53.77109,53.77276,53.76845,53.76845,53.77109,53.76845,53.77109,53.87020,53.87020,53.87020,53.87103,53.88205,53.88205,53.88205,53.88205,53.87701,53.87701,53.87098,53.87098,53.87098,53.86932,53.86932,53.86932,56.51869,56.51869,56.51869,56.55870,56.55870,56.55870,56.55964,56.55964,56.55964,57.51056,57.49542,57.49542,57.50878,57.50878,57.50878,57.45201,57.45477,57.45192,57.45192,57.45192)
y <- c(33.45407,21.40954,27.73487,20.38318,26.65483,31.68201,23.95467,20.77363,32.94192,22.71228,25.78824,28.39449,35.60615,24.29325,22.95047,25.65343,30.23262,22.05534,37.20565,35.53812,38.20211,39.38034,35.16619,38.82336,29.72370,38.25754,26.51339,39.38283,29.57483,31.80111,24.52967,34.83037,21.75038,35.50868,39.41830,21.96971,22.82504,32.69746,35.10747,27.75669,34.96690,37.61921,37.17226,20.50448,39.26582,22.08668,28.41502,36.69530,23.69404,23.18052,33.27420,23.04157,33.17285,32.00579,21.83845,22.97143,32.27190,21.53771,38.65481,20.14341,33.62718,39.86755,39.77881,30.59810,27.65909,24.11646,34.56981,29.30249,34.99361,32.39553,28.90443,34.88775,22.77049,36.44468,30.64496,35.81501,31.77673,24.19058,39.36298,21.47219,23.02268,31.37647,27.28457,33.14749,23.20842,39.73427,39.81399,35.51515,24.55080,39.41190,29.59987,38.46791,20.94479,37.22109,26.36060,30.91641,39.25975,39.88288,22.59061,30.24439,21.66110,30.36878,28.76901,38.75561,33.80408,31.05842,26.18921,21.30804,35.02966,33.85981,30.84373,31.67341,35.07605,37.93820,31.30481,21.45117,37.13626,25.70964,25.64736,38.58381,31.24448,26.55902,23.90817,33.70300,26.48909,37.73200,32.52413,22.44440,28.19878,32.46415,25.13711,26.66075,28.16254,20.40673,39.89327,30.83327,32.40196,39.81218,39.80391,21.87316,34.95792,33.38958,38.18441,22.03114,35.64410,34.90643,24.23056,36.66581,29.35813,20.86880,30.02044,36.13727,24.65558,39.43175,29.00154,29.78185,22.89196,37.15204,35.88188,28.73920,28.04934,37.50701,30.36306,28.39842,35.20973,26.54260,29.57763,26.03163,26.90440,27.60110,25.80086,39.98019,21.59970,28.83825,32.01711,20.50812,38.43331,32.41898,27.68722,32.59905,24.18150,29.05701,22.38512,32.93342,37.66694,37.65391,34.19613,23.89985,36.90012,20.74244,27.08511,29.21433,35.83771,35.59557,33.74533,27.08854,38.38994)
V3 <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Lat, y, as.factor(V3)))
head(df)
```

I plot it on a continuous x-axis as so:

```
df_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Lat, y=y, group=Lat))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=as.factor(V3)))+
  theme_classic()
df_plot
```

Which produces:
[image: boxplot_Q_plot1]
As you can see the boxes are represented as skinny lines.

Therefore I tried to use the `width=` argument as so:

```
df_plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Lat, y=y, group=Lat))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=as.factor(V3)), width=1)+
  theme_classic()
df_plot2
```

The output is:
[image: boxplot_Q_plot2]

The main thing to notice here is that the x-axis range has suddenly changed! Some of the boxes are no longer plotted whilst others seem to be placed at different values of the x-axis.

The range of the x-axis should be:

```
range(df$Lat)
[1] 50.70228 57.88596
```

I am completley perplexed as to why the x-axis would change by simply adding the `width=` argument in `geom_boxplot()`. I therefore tried to force the limits of the x-axis scale as so:

```
df_plot3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Lat, y=y, group=Lat))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=as.factor(V3)), width=1)+
  xlim(50,58)+
  theme_classic()
df_plot3
```

ouput:
[image: boxplot_Q_plot3]

Please send help!

Comment: following up on your request that I take a look at this question.  Seems you already have an answer.  If the answer from @L_W solves your problem, you should consider upvoting and accepting it.  If not, leave a comment to explain what issues remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the strange behaviour comes from ggplot trying to automatically dodge your boxplots apart. By setting `position = position_dodge(width = 0)` the plot seems to be created as expected without changing the placement of boxes along the x-axis. (But gives a warning about overlapping x intervals)

```
Lat<- c(50.70228,50.70228,50.70228,51.82067,51.82067,51.82067,52.45893,52.45893,52.45893,52.76478,52.76478,52.76478,52.78354,52.78354,52.78354,53.56102,53.56102,53.56102,53.65364,53.65364,53.65364,53.63130,53.63130,53.63130,54.19035,54.19035,54.19035,54.25751,54.25751,54.25751,54.23526,54.23526,54.23526,54.62469,54.62469,54.62469,54.67831,54.67831,54.67831,54.67900,54.67900,54.67900,54.94908,54.94908,54.94908,55.19456,55.19456,55.19456,54.79198,54.79198,54.79198,55.34981,55.34981,55.34981,55.85655,55.85655,55.85655,56.06078,56.06078,56.06078,55.84553,55.84553,55.84553,56.00197,56.00197,56.00197,56.71842,56.71842,56.71842,57.00116,57.00116,57.00116,57.06942,57.06942,57.06942,57.26815,57.26815,57.26815,57.45532,57.45532,57.45532,57.88596,57.88596,57.88596,51.07711,51.07711,51.07711,51.07801,51.07621,51.11159,51.11159,51.11159,52.02484,52.02484,52.02484,52.02581,52.02581,52.02581,52.02685,52.02685,52.02685,52.05353,52.05353,52.05626,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,52.05353,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,51.93541,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.92425,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.90810,52.78968,52.78778,52.78968,52.78968,52.78881,52.78883,52.78883,52.78883,52.78970,52.78970,52.79506,52.79506,52.79506,53.77270,53.77276,53.77109,53.77109,53.77276,53.76845,53.76845,53.77109,53.76845,53.77109,53.87020,53.87020,53.87020,53.87103,53.88205,53.88205,53.88205,53.88205,53.87701,53.87701,53.87098,53.87098,53.87098,53.86932,53.86932,53.86932,56.51869,56.51869,56.51869,56.55870,56.55870,56.55870,56.55964,56.55964,56.55964,57.51056,57.49542,57.49542,57.50878,57.50878,57.50878,57.45201,57.45477,57.45192,57.45192,57.45192)
y <- c(33.45407,21.40954,27.73487,20.38318,26.65483,31.68201,23.95467,20.77363,32.94192,22.71228,25.78824,28.39449,35.60615,24.29325,22.95047,25.65343,30.23262,22.05534,37.20565,35.53812,38.20211,39.38034,35.16619,38.82336,29.72370,38.25754,26.51339,39.38283,29.57483,31.80111,24.52967,34.83037,21.75038,35.50868,39.41830,21.96971,22.82504,32.69746,35.10747,27.75669,34.96690,37.61921,37.17226,20.50448,39.26582,22.08668,28.41502,36.69530,23.69404,23.18052,33.27420,23.04157,33.17285,32.00579,21.83845,22.97143,32.27190,21.53771,38.65481,20.14341,33.62718,39.86755,39.77881,30.59810,27.65909,24.11646,34.56981,29.30249,34.99361,32.39553,28.90443,34.88775,22.77049,36.44468,30.64496,35.81501,31.77673,24.19058,39.36298,21.47219,23.02268,31.37647,27.28457,33.14749,23.20842,39.73427,39.81399,35.51515,24.55080,39.41190,29.59987,38.46791,20.94479,37.22109,26.36060,30.91641,39.25975,39.88288,22.59061,30.24439,21.66110,30.36878,28.76901,38.75561,33.80408,31.05842,26.18921,21.30804,35.02966,33.85981,30.84373,31.67341,35.07605,37.93820,31.30481,21.45117,37.13626,25.70964,25.64736,38.58381,31.24448,26.55902,23.90817,33.70300,26.48909,37.73200,32.52413,22.44440,28.19878,32.46415,25.13711,26.66075,28.16254,20.40673,39.89327,30.83327,32.40196,39.81218,39.80391,21.87316,34.95792,33.38958,38.18441,22.03114,35.64410,34.90643,24.23056,36.66581,29.35813,20.86880,30.02044,36.13727,24.65558,39.43175,29.00154,29.78185,22.89196,37.15204,35.88188,28.73920,28.04934,37.50701,30.36306,28.39842,35.20973,26.54260,29.57763,26.03163,26.90440,27.60110,25.80086,39.98019,21.59970,28.83825,32.01711,20.50812,38.43331,32.41898,27.68722,32.59905,24.18150,29.05701,22.38512,32.93342,37.66694,37.65391,34.19613,23.89985,36.90012,20.74244,27.08511,29.21433,35.83771,35.59557,33.74533,27.08854,38.38994)
V3 <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Lat, y, as.factor(V3)))

df_plot <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=as.factor(V3), x=Lat, y=y, group=as.factor(Lat)),
               position=position_dodge(width = 0),
               width=1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: boxplot with overlapping boxes]

Comment: Hi @L_W - thank you so much for your clear and much need answer!