# How to plot a boxplot with correctly spaced continuous x-axis values and a grouping variable in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot with a continuous x-axis where the x-axis labels are correctly spaced by their numeric value. I found the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245233/how-to-plot-a-boxplot-with-correctly-spaced-continuous-x-axis-values-in-ggplot2) helpful, but my data also has a grouping variable within each year.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- rep(c('1','1', '10', '10', '11', '11' ,'20', '20'), 2)
y <- runif(16, 1,20)
class <- rep(c('in', 'out'), 8)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y=y, class=class)
df$x_int <- as.integer(df$x)
```

If I don't use the variable `class` then I can use the `group` argument to achieve the right spacing on the x-axis.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x_int, y=y, group=Year_int))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

But when I add `fill=class`, it doesn't appear to do anything and produces the exact same plot.

I would like the boxplot to show the `class` grouping in each year (shown below), but have the correct x-axis spacing from the first plot.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=class))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data, you have a discrete variable, i.e., `class`. However, you need the data to be grouped by `class` and `x_int`. So, we can specify this grouping by using `interaction` in the group argument  for `x_int` and `class`. Then, fill with `class`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x_int, y=y, group = interaction(x_int, class), fill = class)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

**Output**

[image]